# OS X Cocoa concurrency: how to return control to the UI after a task is launched

Tags: cocoa, concurrency

I have a calculation task that will take some time to complete.  Minutes.  Maybe several minutes.  I want to launch the task with a button on the UI, then return to the UI so that the user can interact with other areas while the task is running.

I modeled my code after an example from Apple's Concurrency Programming Guide:

```
// code here to initialize the c++ objects a, b, c, and d as ivars.

- (NSOperation*)taskWithData:(id)data 
{
    NSInvocationOperation* theOp = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] 
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(myTaskMethod:) 
                                        object:nil] autorelease];
       return theOp;
}

// This is the method that does the actual work of the task.
- (void)myTaskMethod:(id)data 
{
    // Perform the task.
    task(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Then I call `myTaskMethod:data`  from within the button's IBAction:

```
-(void)actionButtonPushed:(id)sender
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* myPool = [NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self myTaskMethod:nil];
    [myPool drain];
}
```

I hoped that control would return to the UI, but it doesn't.  We don't return to the UI until `myTaskMethod:` finishes its business ... exactly the same behavior as if I called `task()` directly in the IBAction code.

More details:  this code is Objective-C++  (.mm), and task(); is a c++ function.

If it's not obvious, this is my first attempt at using Concurrency;  I need some direction, please.

tia, g

Update: Fixed.  I had neglected to create an SNOperationQueue, and add my NSOperation to the queue.

Comment: Add your fix as an accepted answer so future viewers can easily see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Fixed. I had neglected to create an SNOperationQueue, and add my NSOperation to the queue.